# Add data to order overview table

Tags: shopware, shopware6

The order overview has predefined list settings as shown in this example for the customer overview: https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/wiki-assets.shopware.com/1606474738/Verkaufskanaele_KundenZuweisung-Kundenuebersicht-Spalten_EN.PNG

I want to show more than the predefined data in the overview, for example the customer email.

Is it possible to alter the list settings? I could not find any documentation on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to extend this VueJs module:

https://github.com/shopware/shopware/tree/trunk/src/Administration/Resources/app/administration/src/module/sw-customer/page/sw-customer-list

A starting point for extending the module, can be found in this documentation:

https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/administration/using-mixins.html